How to change the default library when downgrade the targetSdk version
When I want to create a new Android project in Android Studio, the defaul targetSdk will always be the latest one (for now is 34), but What I want is the lower one. The IDE will show me the error when I downgrade the Sdk version.
But these library I didn't implementation on my project yet. How to adjust these default library versions and where are they coming from?

I assume that it's casused by AGP, but I read the doc about AGP, it seems it will help to package with gradle only, no description about pre-install the libray.

You can open your app level build.gradle file and replace the app compat dependencies with the one compatible with your target sdk
You can select the versions here

After digging some reviews I found that it's caused by the com.google.android.material library which the IDE imports for me when I create a new project. It not only import the material UI but also some base Android Component such as viewModel, LiveData and lifecycle. Downgrade the version number and It works.
